# Adding and removing class with jquery when content changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-countdown

I'm working with [countdown.js](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/) to make a countdown counter. I am basically trying to emulate the counter from the front page, but this one just counts down to new year, I want to be able to edit the date (this I've done).

What I have is this (for example for seconds)

```
<div class="countdown_inner flip'">
    <div class="countdown second curr top" id="second"></div>
    <div class="countdown second next top"></div>
    <div class="countdown second next bottom"></div>
    <div class="countdown second curr bottom"></div>
    <span>Seconds</span>
</div>
```

the next `number` and `curr` are changing every second (counting down - the number is generated via `countdown.js` inisde those divs). I need to remove, and then add the `flip` class every time that changes happens. This is what happens on the page from the author. His code differs from mine quite a bit, so I cannot just copy and paste it. Every time a change happens on minutes, hours etc, `flip` will disappear and appear again after a second.
I tried with several jquery handlers, but no luck (`.on('change')`, or something similar).

EDIT: Fixed the code.

Comment: `id` should be unique in a document. You've multiple elements with same `id` which is invalid...

Comment: for every second you want to add / remove `flip` class from `countdown_inner' div, is it right?

Comment: id be unique in html

Comment: Oh, I'll fix the id thing, thanks for pointing it out! @BhushanKawadkar yes, that's right, but I have other similar divs, with different ids, so the `flip` should happen when change happens (in seconds it's every second, in minutes it's every 60 seconds, etc.)

Comment: [my exmaple](http://jsfiddle.net/c2Lzhe1r/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use you `.on('update.countdown',callback)`

activity :

```
$('div#clock').countdown(finalDate)
    .on('update.countdown', callback)
    .on('finish', callback);
```

example :

```
<div class="some"></div>
<div class="some"></div>
<div class="some"></div>
<div class="some"></div>
```

jquery

`event.offset` => months,weeks,days,hours,minutes,seconds

```
$('.some').each(function(){
    $(this)
    .countdown('2015/10/10 12:34:56')
    .on('update.countdown', function(event){
        var format = '%M:%S';
        if(event.offset.minutes % 2 == 1){ //odd number
            console.log('odd number');
            $(this).addClass('flip');
        } 
        if (event.offset.minutes % 2 == 0){ //numbered 
            console.log('numbered ');
            $(this).removeClass('flip');
        }
        $(this).html(event.strftime(format));
    });
});
```

Comment: Jep, this is it, I just need to rewrite my code completly because I used id's etc. But this is the gist of it :D

Answer (score -1):

you can use the functions .removeClass('CLASSNAME') / .addClass('CLASSNAME');

Try with:

```
$("#WHATEVER").removeClass('CLASSNAME U WANT TO REMOVE')
$("#WHATEVER").addClass('CLASSNAME U WANT TO REMOVE');
```

Hope it helps you ;)

Comment: I know I can add and remove classes with that, it's just that I need to add and remove class when content inside divs changes ;) And that depends kinda on the plugin...